# Got this error When I use "gradle clean" for an Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/user/AndroidCode/MyProject/build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.

  > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

line:1 is apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: Which java version and also Gradle version do you have ?

Comment: as suggested by gradle it would be helpful to see the stacktrace. so try to run with `--stacktrace`